# Can't see my custom dimensions in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I want to have some custom dimensions and metrics in my Google Analytics site, but that data never appears. So, I've:

### Step 1 - Create it in Google Analytics

Going throw Admin, I've created the metric with index of 1. **It was created 3 days ago**, I've read you have to wait at least one day, but has not been shown. This is my custom metric. Notice I've made a change today (set scope to hit).

[image]

### Step 2 - Set de data

Just before the closing body tag, it's written

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
/* GA CODE */
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'dimensionHarcodeada');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

### Step 3 - Analyze if data is being sent

Thanks to the GA Debug extension, I can verify data is being sent

[image]

### Step 4 - Verify custom dimension in Google Analytics

**Is missing**. Navigating into Custom > Custom variables, nothing appears:

[image]

Causes?

- Am I setting **the right scope?** when creating the custom dimension? As told in step one, now it is set as **hit**. This is the information sent to GA

[image]

Comment: You are confusing custom dimensions and custom variables. You can select custom dimension as secondary dimension in your reports or use them in custom reports (also in segments and filters). Custom variables is a deprecated feature not supported by Universal Analytics.